# Display viewmodel data from controller in view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to display the query results in a Razor view.

I get the desired output by controller, but I need help to show in view.

Class `Fuel`:

```
public class Fuel
{
    public int FuelId { get; set; }
    public int FMonth{ get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Class `Location`:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now I join both table using a view model class `FuelLocation`:

```
 public class FuelLocation
 {
    public Fuel Fuels { get; set; }
    public Location Locations { get; set; }       
 }
```

Here is action method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult EmpDetails()
{
    var res = (from loc in _context.Locations
               join Fl in _context.Fuels on loc.Name equals Fl.Locationn
               select new FuelLocation
                       {
                           Fuels = Fl,
                           Locations = loc
                       }).GroupBy(c => c.Fuels.Locationn)
              .Select(g => new
              {
                  Location = g.Key,
                  Jan = g.Where(c => c.Fuels.FMonth == 1).Sum(c => c.Fuels.Sale),
                  Feb = g.Where(c => c.Fuels.FMonth == 2).Sum(c => c.Fuels.Sale),
                  March = g.Where(c => c.Fuels.FMonth == 3).Sum(c => c.Fuels.Sale)
              }).ToList();
}
```

The result of this query is:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkJcL.png)

and I want to show it like this

```
Name    | Jan       | Feb       | Mar   | Total
1       | 100       | 350       |  250  | 700
2       | 200       | 220       | 2150  | 2170
```

My Razor view:

```
 @model IList<COSAuthNew.Services.Generic.FuelLocation>
        <h2>Index</h2>
        <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>LocationName</th>
                    <th>Jan</th>
                    <th>Feb</th>
                    <th>March</th>
                     <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    //Plz enter your solution 
                }
```

but I did not get a proper result which I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To display the item values just add the `@` before the value in the td-tag. Then you can sum the values in the last column using `@(val1 + val2..)`

```
@model IList<COSAuthNew.Services.Generic.FuelLocation>
        <h2>Index</h2>
        <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>LocationName</th>
                    <th>Jan</th>
                    <th>Feb</th>
                    <th>March</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <td>@item.Location</td>
                    <td>@item.Jan</td>
                    <td>@item.Feb</td>
                    <td>@item.March</td>
                    <td>@(item.Jan + item.Feb + item.March)</td>
                }
```

Comment: dear please focus on fuel class there is no proprty for "jan","Feb","March"

Comment: then how we display on view like 
<td>@item.Location</td>
                    <td>@item.Jan</td>
                    <td>@item.Feb</td>
                    <td>@item.March</td>

Answer (score 0):

For `Razor View`, you need to return a view model which contains `Location` and `Jan` properties.

- Define view model like below:

  ```
   public class FuelLocationVM
   {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Jan { get; set; }
        public int Feb { get; set; }
        public int March { get; set; }
   }
  ```
- Return VM instead of anoymous type

  ```
      var res = (from loc in _context.Locations
         join Fl in _context.Fuels on loc.Name equals Fl.Locationn
         select new FuelLocation
                 {
                     Fuels = Fl,
                     Locations = loc
                 }).GroupBy(c => c.Fuels.Locationn)
        .Select(g => new FuelLocationVM
        {
            Location = g.Key,
            Jan = g.Where(c => c.Fuels.FMonth == 1).Sum(c => c.Fuels.Sale),
            Feb = g.Where(c => c.Fuels.FMonth == 2).Sum(c => c.Fuels.Sale),
            March = g.Where(c => c.Fuels.FMonth == 3).Sum(c => c.Fuels.Sale)
        }).ToList();
  ```
- Reference VM in razor view

  ```
      @model IList<COSAuthNew.Services.Generic.FuelLocationVM>
  <h2>Index</h2>
  <table class="table">
          <tr>
              <th>LocationName</th>
              <th>Jan</th>
              <th>Feb</th>
              <th>March</th>
               <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
          @foreach (var item in Model)
          {
              <td>@item.Location</td>
              <td>@item.Jan</td>
              <td>@item.Feb</td>
              <td>@item.March</td>
              <td>@(item.Jan + item.Feb + item.March)</td> 
          }
  ```